# Is my logical statement correct?

Tags: logic

Wolf’s *A Mathematical Tour Through Mathematical Logic*, Section 1.3, Exercise 5:

> **Exercise 5.** Translate the following statements into symbolic form, as in the previous example.
>
> (a) All crows are black, but not all black things are crows.
> (b) If everybody complains, no one will get help.
> (c) Everybody loves somebody sometime.

My attempt at (a):
Let $C(x)$ be the statement “$x$ is a crow”, where $x$ is the variable whose domain is all the things, living or non living.
Let $B(x)$ be the statement “$x$ is black”, where $x$ has the same domain as above.
So I think it should translate as $$\forall x(C(x)\rightarrow B(x)).$$

Is it correct?

Comment: Your formula is the correct transaltion of "All crows are black".

Comment: How do you answer (c)?

Comment: @harshatech2012 I’d translate it like this. Let $P(x,y, t)$ be the statement that “$x$ loves $y$ at time $t$” where $x,y$ range over all the humans and $t$ ranges over time. Then I’d write $\forall x\exists y\exists t P(x,y,t)$.

Comment: @Atom Yes, it's a possible solution. See this question for more answers: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3742919/493216

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer is partially correct since you did not translate "but not all black things are crows" part. You first can interpret it as "there is a black thing that is not a crow" and translate it as 
$$\exists x(B(x) \land \lnot C(x))$$

Now, can you connect this with your answer?