# logic - natural language to symbolic form

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

How to translate the following natural-language statements to symbolic form:

- "If everybody complains, no one will get help"

  - Is this correct? $\forall x C(x) \rightarrow \lnot (\forall y H(y))$, where $C(x)$ is "x is complaining" and $H(y)$ is "y gets help"
- "Everybody loves somebody sometime"

  - "Everybody loves somebody" becomes $\forall x \exists y L(x,y)$, where $L(x,y)$ is "x loves y". But how to translate `sometime`?

**PS:** this question is a follow-up to an [old question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3252873/493216).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your first one is incorrect; as you have written, you are saying that if everyone complains, then not everyone gets help (that is, at least one person does not get help). It should probably be
$$\left( \forall x Cx\right) \longrightarrow \left( \forall y\left(\neg Hy\right)\right)$$
or equivalently,
$$\left( \forall x Cx\right) \longrightarrow \neg\left(\exists y Hy\right).$$

For the second, I think you need a ternary relation, something like $L(x,y,t)$ to mean “$x$ loves $y$ at time $t$”. Then you could write
$$\forall x\exists y\exists t L(x,y,t).$$

Answer (score 2):

I would symbolize the first statement like this:

$$\forall x(Cx) \to \neg \exists y(Hy)$$

I believe your symbolization is incorrect because $\neg (\forall y Hy)$ is equivalent to $\exists y \neg Hy$ ("There exists a y such that y does not get help" You're looking for "Nobody gets help").

Now, I would symbolize "Everybody loves someone" as

$$\forall x \exists y(Lxy)$$

which is pretty much exactly how you symbolized it.

As for "sometime," I'm not exactly sure how you would symbolize the time in this context. Perhaps you can use [temporal logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_logic#:%7E:text=In%20logic%2C%20temporal%20logic%20is,until%20I%20eat%20something%22). This would require you to be pretty familiar with modal logic, though. It depends on how you interpret "sometime," which, in my opinion, is pretty ambiguous.